# Django serializer does not throw error for flawed validated data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am running a django application and I have a simple class-based django-rest `CreateView`. My problem is that data actually gets created even though I sent flawed data. I am not entirely sure if that's expected behaviour, but I think it shouldn't be.

View is simple:

```
class ModelCreate(CreateAPIView):
    """Create instance"""

    serializer_class = ModelCreateSerializer
    queryset = ModelCreate.objects.all()
```

In my serializer I am overwriting the create method for some custom behaviour and I am adding two write-only fields that I need for my data creation:

```
 class ModelCreate(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize objects."""

    field_extra1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    field_extra2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelCreate
        fields = (
            "field_extra1",
            "field_extra2",
            "field3",
            "field4",
            "field5",
            "field6",
            "field7",
            ...
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create obj and relate to other model."""

        field_extra1 = validated_data.pop("field_extra1")
        field_extra2 = validated_data.pop("field_extra2")
        obj = Model.objects.get(name=field_extra1)
        relation = obj.objects.filter(name=field_extra2)[0]
        validated_data["relation"] = relation
        result = ModelCreate.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return result
```

My model has many optional fields.

```
   field_fk = models.ForeignKey(
        Model,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="building_objects",
    )
   field_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(
        Model,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )
   field3 = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    field4 = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)],
    )
    field5 = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)]
    )
    field6 = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)],
    )
    field7 = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)],
    )
```

Now what happens is that if I send a random made up extra field in my JSON the data gets created  and the validated data just ignores the field:

Let's say I send data like this:

```
data = {
        "field_extra1": "foo",
        "field_extra2": "foo",
        "field3": "bar",
        "field3": "bar",
        "bullshit-field": "bullshitvalue",
    }


r = requests.request(
"post",
json=data,
 url=url,
)

print(r.status_code)
```

It creates the data without complaints.

What I expected is that the the serializer should notice that there is a bullshitfield and throw an error. Because what happens when I have a typo, it just ignores the field alltogether. So I doubt that this is the desired behaviour.

If this is in fact the standard behaviour is there a way to change it?

Thanks in advance for hints and help! Very much appreciated.

Comment: you can send at least one hundred different fields in the request, and the serializer will not throw an error. It will only throw an error if there is no required field. Or for example, in the field where the string should be, the number was sent

Comment: @ТаалайДюшебеков Thanks!! Understood. So you are saying this is the standard, expected behaviour and if I want to change that I need to make the fields required... If you want, put it in an answer so I can accept it

Comment: No, not entirely true. Let's say we have a model with 10 fields. You have created a serializer in which all of these fields are required.
And you send a request that has all 10 fields. Everything will work fine. But if you add other fields to the request, the request will still work. The whole point is that the serializer searches in the request body for a field defined in the meta class as fields. All other fields will be ignored

Comment: in your data you have `"bullshit-field": "bullshitvalue"`. Serializer cant check this field. He will ignore it. He will start check this field only if you add him to fields in Meta. But after that he will ignore `"bullshit-field1": "bullshitvalue1"` and all other that not in fields in Meta

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense. But then I can't really protect against spelling mistakes by the user because the serializer will ignore the misspelled name because it thinks it's a field that doesn't exist....For example, when I add `bullshit-field` to my serializer and the user types `bulshit-field`, it will be again ignored....

Comment: lol man)
The point is that a person does not have to enter a field key. He must only enters the value.

Comment: haha :). Yes, but only if I use the rest-interface. But if the user sends the raw data the user can also specify the keys.... I thought I can somehow also validate this

Comment: In this case, you write documentation for users with field names and their types. And the user must respect the field names described in this documentation. There is no other way. Good luck))

Comment: Will do my friend! Thank you!